# Запустить jquery функцию после смены позиции курсора

Tags: javascript, jquery, ace

Мне необходимо запускать jquery функцию после смены позиции курсора. Пробовал следующим образом:

```
$('ace_cursor').on( 'change', function(){
    console.log('Position changed')
});
```

В консоле нечего не появилось, функция не вызывается

Comment: Что такое ace_cursor? Может подумать в сторону метода mousemove для body или того объекта, внутри которого курсор движется?

Comment: change сработает только если что изменится

Comment: Как вариант - [jquery-position-event](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-position-event). Там же найдёте и [демо](https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/GRgjgad)

Comment: У курсора меняется стиль, а именно left. Можно ли как-то сделать событие, когда меняется стиль элемента?

Answer (score 0):

Если смотреть на события мыши в браузере то их [несколько](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_mouseevent.asp)

```
onclick, oncontextmenu, ondblclick, onmousedown, onmouseenter, onmouseleave, onmousemove,  
onmouseout, onmouseover, onmouseup
```

что бы получить change думаю нужно поработать над комбинацией событий.